# How can I centre a div between 2 floating divs

Tags: css, html, dreamweaver, centering

hi I am having a problem centering my content div between my left and right sidebars. My left and ride side bars are floating and there isn't a `float:center`. The only way I can center it is using padding but that makes my center div go underneath my sidebars.

Comment: can you show your html?

Comment: better you give a JSFIDDLE

Comment: this is my css                                           .leftsidebar {
 height: 608px;
 width: 163px;
 background-image: url(../images/bg_leftbar.png);
}

.rightsidebar {
 background-image: url(../images/rightside_bar.png);
 height: 608px;
 width: 163px;
 float:right;
}
.content {
 width: 500px;
 margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
 clear:both;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working [one](http://jsfiddle.net/N3qmH/2/). 
Use **margin: 0 auto;** will get your element centered most of the time. (Quick note: your element must have a declared width for this to work.)

The **margin: 0 auto;** rule is shorthand for 0 top and bottom margin, and automatic left and right margins. Automatic left and right margins work together to push the element into the center of its container.

The **margin: 0 auto;** setting doesn't work perfectly in every centering situation, but it works in a whole lot of them.

reference: [You Can't Float Center with CSS](http://www.codeitpretty.com/2012/05/you-cant-float-center.html)
 
**HTML**

```
<div class="leftsidebar">a</div>
<div class="rightsidebar">b</div>
<div class="content">c</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.leftsidebar 
{ 
height: 608px; 
width: 60px; 
background:red; 
float:left; } 

.rightsidebar 
{ 
background:blue; 
height: 608px; 
width: 163px; 
float:right; 
} 

.content 
{ 
width: auto; //or any width that you want
margin:0 auto;
background:yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

make a wrapper around all 3 divs and then position the centered div with a margin

```
<div id="wrap">
 <div id="left" style="float: left"></div>
 <div id="content" stlye="float: left: margin: 0 auto;"></div>
 <div id="right" stlye="float: left"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Floatting basis would be:

```
<div id="left"> Left</div>
<div id="right" >right</div>
<div id="middle">in between, but after</div>
```

```
#left {float:left;width:XX;}
#right {float:right;width:XX;}
#middle {overflow:hidden; margin:0 XX;}
```

You can as well look for other methods to keep div in the flow [left][middle][right], like using : display: table/table-cell | inline-block | flex.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="widht: 960px;">
    <div class="content left">left</div>
     <div class="content center">center</div>
      <div class="content right">right</div>
      <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

here the css

```
.content {
float: left;
}

.left , .right{
width : 180px;
margin : 0 10px;
}

.center{
widht: 540px;
margin : 0 10px;
```

}